# JQuery & XML: page duplicates its content for every template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xslt

I've set up a radio broadcast station and I have a "now playing" tag where the current artist is displayed. I've written a little jQuery code so that only that part of the webpage updates every second, so that the "now playing" info is displayed correctly.
But I have multiple streams that the user can choose from... i.e. Rock, pop, R&B,...

The problem now is that for every stream, the page duplicates itself. So the whole content of the page is displayed 8 times AND the layout is messed up.

The page loads just fine, but after 10 seconds it updates the tag and then the layout is duplicated 8 times, but it only happens the first time it updates.

Below is my XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0" >
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:template match = "/icestats" >
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).load(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $(".streamdataArtist").load("status.xsl");
        }, 10000);
    });
</script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
window.onload = startTime;
function startTime()
{
    var date = new Date();
    var uur = date.getHours();
    var min = date.getMinutes();
    var sec = date.getSeconds();

    if(min == 0 || min == 1 || min == 2 || min == 3 || min ==4 || min == 5 || min == 6 || min == 7 || min == 8 || min == 9)
    {
        min = "0" + min;
    }
    if(sec == 0 || sec == 1 || sec == 2 || sec == 3 || sec ==4 || sec == 5 || sec == 6 || sec == 7 || sec == 8 || sec == 9)
    {
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }       

var movingtime = uur + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = movingtime;
        setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}
</script>
<title>Muziekserver</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">
<h2>Overzicht aanbod</h2>
<br />
<!--index header menu -->
<div class="roundcont">
<div class="roundtop">
<img src="/corner_topleft.jpg" class="corner" style="display: none" />
</div>
<table border="0" width="100%" id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1px">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#656565">
        <a class="nav" href="admin/">Administratie</a>
        <a class="nav" href="status.xsl">Overzicht van muziek</a>
        </td>
        <td id="clockcell">
        <span id="clock" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="roundbottom">
<img src="/corner_bottomleft.jpg" class="corner" style="display: none" />
</div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<!--end index header menu -->
<!--mount point stats-->
<xsl:for-each select="source">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="listeners">
<div class="roundcont">
<div class="roundtop">
<img src="/corner_topleft.jpg" class="corner" style="display: none" />
</div>
<div class="newscontent">
    <div class="streamheader">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <colgroup align="left" />
            <colgroup align="right" width="300" />
            <tr>
                <td><h3>Naam:  <xsl:value-of select="@mount" /></h3></td>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="authenticator">
                        <td align="right"><a class="auth" href="/auth.xsl">Login</a></td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <td align="right"> Speel af als <a href="{@mount}.m3u">MP3</a> of als <a href="{@mount}.xspf">XSPF</a></td>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </tr></table>
    </div>

<table border="0" cellpadding="4" id="info">
<xsl:if test="server_name">
<tr><td>Naam</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="server_name" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="server_description">
<tr><td>Beschrijving</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="server_description" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="genre">
<tr><td>Genre</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="genre" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="bitrate">
<tr><td>Bitrate</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="bitrate" /> kbps</td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="quality">
<tr><td>Quality:</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="quality" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="video_quality">
<tr><td>Video Quality:</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="video_quality" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="frame_size">
<tr><td>Framesize:</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="frame_size" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="frame_rate">
<tr><td>Framerate:</td><td class="streamdata"> <xsl:value-of select="frame_rate" /></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="server_url">
<tr><td>URL</td><td class="streamdata"> <a target="_blank" href="{server_url}"><xsl:value-of select="server_url" /></a></td></tr>
</xsl:if>
<tr><td>Nu bezig</td><td class="streamdataArtist"> 
<xsl:if test="artist"><xsl:value-of select="artist" /> - </xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="roundbottom">
<img src="/corner_bottomleft.jpg" class="corner" style="display: none" />
</div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<h3><xsl:value-of select="@mount" /> - Not Connected</h3>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;</xsl:text>nbsp;


</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an empty template that matches the root node to prevent the [built-in template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) from printing every time the stylesheet is called:

```
<xsl:template match="/" />
```